# Link two processes Bash

Tags: bash

I have two command line programs, a client application and a server application it talks to.

The client depends on the server running in the background.  I can launch both via:

`java  -jar server.jar & java -jar client.jar`

When I kill the client, however, the server remains in the background.  Is there a way to link the two so that if the client dies, the server dies?

Comment: This is probably not actually doing what you expect, you have two commands, `java  -jar server.jar &`, and `java -jar client.jar`. This is going to spawn the server in the background, and the client in the forground. Control+C will only kill the client, as the server has already been backgrounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the server job in the background and store process id using `$!`. Then run the client.
After the client exits, kill the server using the stored pid, like this:

```
java  -jar server.jar &
server=$!
java -jar client.jar
kill $server
```

shorter: no need to store PID of the background process, there's only one

```
java  -jar server.jar &
java -jar client.jar
kill $!
```

Comment: Don't use `kill -9`, which doesn't give the server a chance to clean up after itself. `kill` (which sends `SIGTERM` should be sufficient; if it is not, try `kill -INT`.

Comment: edited! I wanted to make sure my test worked (I'm running windows / MSYS where `kill` doesn't use signals)

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that the client dies whenever the server dies _and_ vice versa?

Comment: more difficult, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to link them, but you can manage the processes explicitly.

```
java -jar server.jar & server_pid=$!
java -jar client.jar
kill $server_pid
```

The server runs in the background, then the client runs in the foreground. The script blocks at this point, so when the client exits, the script proceeds with the next command, which kills the server.